# Running Laravel artisan queue:work on docker container startup

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-queue

I am trying to get

`php artisan queue:work`

command to run when my docker container starts up, so that it will keep running and processing jobs.
I need to do this using 'Dockerfile'.

I can run it by doing exec -it when the container is running.

But I need to do it using Dockerfile so that when my container deploys, it starts this automatically.
I have tried

```
RUN php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work

CMD ["php","/var/www/html/artisan","queue:work"]

ENTRYPOINT ["php","/var/www/html/artisan","queue:work"]
```

seperately ofcourse. but none of them work. In case of CMD and ENTRYPOINT my container starts giving out 502 error and my service becomes inaccessible.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define the full php path. For example, in my case (Alpine Linux) is:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

So, your ENTRYPOINT will look like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/php","/var/www/html/artisan","queue:work"]
```

Assuming you are on Linux, please run:

```
which php
```

in order to determine the full path.

Comment: the output does not complain about not being able to find `php`.. it's in the path.